# How to not allow user to enter duplicate entry in an object in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created a program to enter student details like name and roll number. The roll number has to unique and user cannot add multiple record for same roll number. I have created 3 classes, student class, stuMaster class having `ArrayList` and main class when the main function is being called.
Following is the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean exit = false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter any option from below:");
        System.out.println("1 Enter new student");
        System.out.println("2 View all students");
        System.out.println("3 Exit");

        switch (input.nextInt()) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter the details of student: ");
            StuMaster stm = new StuMaster();
            stm.addStudentDetails();
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("All the records are: ");
            StuMaster stm1 = new StuMaster();
            stm1.displayAllStudents();

        case 3:
            exit = true;
            System.exit(0);

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid entry!");
        }

    } while (!exit);
}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student {

private int rollNumber, marks;
public name;

public Student() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter roll number: ");
    rollNumber = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    name= input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter marks: ");
    marks = input.nextInt();
}

public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + name + "Roll no.: " + rollNumber + " ,Marks :" + marks;
}

public int getRollNo() {
    return this.rollNumber;
}
```

StuMaster class where List is called and the method to add students is defined:

```
public class StuMaster {

static List<Student> stu = new ArrayList<Student>();
Student stuObj = new Student();

public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return stu;
}

public void addStudentDetails() {   

    stu.add(stuObj);
    System.out.println("Student record added! Following are the details that you added: \n" + stuObj);
}

public void displayAllStudents() {
    System.out.println("All the students in the system: ");
    for (Student s1 : stu) {
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

I'm new to java, and unable to understand how to apply check in the `StuMaster` class in the `addStudentDetails` method.

Comment: In `Student.java`, override `equals()` and `hashCode()`. In `StuMaster.java`, use a `Set` instead of a `List`.

Answer (score 4):

Your program needs to use `Set` instead of `List` if you don't want to have duplicates in your collection. But, I will show you a program a little bit modified from the original one, which in my opinion is better from some points of view :

1) Remove the unnecessary instantiation of `StuMaster` for every iteration

2) Remove the creation of student attributes from the constructor

3) Better readability

```
public class Student {
private String name;
private int rollNumber;
private int mark;

public Student(String name, int rollNumber, int mark) {
    this.name = name;
    this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    this.mark = mark;
}

//equals and hashcode 

@Override
public String toString() {
   //to string override
}
}
```

You can override the hashcode and equals method using [this](https://mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/) tutorial.

```
public class StudentManager {
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();

public void addStudent(Student student) {
    students.add(student);
}

public void displayStudents() {
    for (Student student : students) {
        System.out.println(student);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the public static void main method for your menu :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean exit = false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    StudentManager studentManager = new StudentManager();

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter any option from below:");
        System.out.println("1 Enter new student");
        System.out.println("2 View all students");
        System.out.println("3 Exit");

        switch (input.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter the details of student: ");
                Student student = createStudent(input);
                studentManager.addStudent(student);
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("All the records are: ");
                studentManager.displayStudents();
                break;

            case 3:
                exit = true;
                System.exit(0);

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid entry!");
        }

    } while (!exit);
    }
```

And a new method to create a student based on the inputs :

```
public static Student createStudent(Scanner input) {
    System.out.println("Enter roll number: ");
    int rollNumber = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    String name = input.next();

    System.out.println("Enter marks: ");
    int marks = input.nextInt();

    return new Student(name, rollNumber, marks);
}
```

**PS** : A `break` added for `case 2` otherwise it would have exited your program every time when you wanted to display the students.

Comment: @sebestian Thanks for the solution. However, I am facing one issue that I forgot to mention in the above question. One of the variable in the student class is extended from another class person which another variable address. So, it is like:
    `Class Student extends Person(){
       public Student(String name, String address, int rollno, int marks){
         super(address); this.name = name; this.roll = rollno; this.marks = marks}

I have created getter & setter in the person class from address.The problem is that how to use that getter setter in static createStudent method for address?

Comment: You can create the address like you created the other attributes. 

System.out.println("Enter address: ");
    String address = input.next(); 

Then you simply add this parameter in the constructor signature: Student(address,name,rollNumber,marks);